# Applying position relative and then position:absolute makes the div stretch across the container?

Tags: html, css, position, twitter-bootstrap

Here's my code..

```
<div id="secondWrapper">
    <div class="para1">  
      <div class="heading">
        <h1>Heading 1</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="paragraph">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec at ipsum in nunc dignissim fringilla. Donec porta elit ut diam eleifend eget rhoncus risus dignissim. Vivamus malesuada accumsan molestie. Maecenas lobortis, ipsum sit amet mattis tincidunt, turpis odio tempus massa, at scelerisque elit diam id dolor. 
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="para2">  
      <div class="heading">
        <h1>Heading 2</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="paragraph">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec at ipsum in nunc dignissim fringilla. Donec porta elit ut diam eleifend eget rhoncus risus dignissim. Vivamus malesuada accumsan molestie. Maecenas lobortis, ipsum sit amet mattis tincidunt, turpis odio tempus massa, at scelerisque elit diam id dolor. 
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="social_icons">
      <a class="btn" href="#">
          <i class="icon-twitter-sign icon-large"></i> Follow us on Twitter</a>

      <a class="btn" href="#">
          <i class="icon-facebook-sign icon-large"></i> Find us on Facebook</a>

      <a class="btn" href="#">
         <i class="icon-facetime-video icon-large"></i> Subscribe on Youtube</a>
    </div>
  </div><!-- /container -->
```

And CSS...

```
    #secondWrapper{
    height:144px;
    width:740px;
    margin:0 auto;
    position: relative
    }

.para1 {
    width:211px;
    padding-right: 39px;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left
}

.para2 {
    width:211px;
    padding-right: 39px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

.social_icons {
    width: 211px
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
}

.heading {
    padding-bottom:31px;
}

.paragraph {
    width:211px;
}
```

Here's my problem. With the above code the social icons that are contained in the `social_icons` div are floating to the top of the div and not really giving me the look that im looking for.

So, I want to position them to the bottom of the div so they are more inkeeping with the rest of the text on the page. One way of doing this (so says Google). Is to apply `position: absolute` to my container div (`secondWrapper`) and then apply `position:relative` and `bottom: 0` to the `social_icons` div.

However, when I do this it just stretches the divs contents across my page and disregards the `width` constraint that ive already applied.

Does anyone know of another way to get the solution that im looking for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not really taking advantage of the bootstrap grid system. You can easily rewrite what you have to support it and not have to resort to `position:absolute` to do it.

First off, you're creating your own container, the bootstrap already has some `.span` classes made for you that you can use to your liking, so you can rewrite your markup using them like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span4">
      ....
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
      ....
   </div>
    <div class="social_icons span4">
      ....
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then you can style the your social icons easily by just targeting the `span` container with your own class.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rzSFa/)

Comment: This is much tidier than my suggestion and it makes use of the ready made grid system in Twitter Bootstrap!

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding it correctly they what you actually want to do is set the container div `secondWrapper` to `position: relative` and then set the inner div, `social_icons` div to `position:absolute`.

I can't see any positioning in your example, but if you want to edit your question with the current version of the code which includes the positioning then I will take a look.

Is this the kind of thing you are looking for?
http://jsfiddle.net/dannymcc/tXFTt/1/embedded/result/

If so, take a look at the code
http://jsfiddle.net/dannymcc/tXFTt/1/

Rather than using each of the buttons classes I have used :nth-child(1) because you've used the same class for each of the buttons.

I also set a height for the third div which may need altering once you've completed the font changes etc.

There is likely a better way to do this if you're using Twitter bootstrap or similar. This is just a quick and dirty way of getting it done.

Comment: I didn't post it with the positing as that is what was giving me the problem. Ive updated my first post though with the positioning suggestions you've made.

Comment: Could you provide a quick sketch of how you expect the page to display?

Comment: This is how the code is currently rendering the divs http://jsfiddle.net/dannymcc/tXFTt/ what do you want to happen? Do you want the social icons underneath the left div?